# What rules and conventions should a class follow to be able to work properly with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, poco, mygeneration

I am working on a code template to create POCOs from my Db Schema.

Is there a kind of summary list that defines the MUST-TO-HAVEs in a class so that it can be mapped to Db with NHibernate without any problem.

(As I know, one of the rules is to have your properties virtual so that NHibernate proxies can override)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using NHibernate directly. Instead I'm using Castle ActiveRecord which is a wrapper around it and works completely declarative. I just can tell you, that ActiveRecord does'nt require any changes to your code to work.

Answer (score 3):

well, besides the `virtual` properties you must also:

- have a parameter-less constructor, even if `private/protected`
- have a property (or combination of properties) that identify an object (usually the primary key of the table)
- override `int GetHashCode()` and `bool Equals(object obj)` by using the aforementioned object identifier in their body